# why field name getting 'none' in django templates

Tags: python, django

I created templates page and retrieving data from the model for one field I am getting none and displays Class name of the model,

template code:

```
    {% for abc in events %}
            <div>

                <h2><a href="">{{ abc.event_title }}</a></h2>
                <p>published: {{ abc.event_release_date }}</p>

                <p>{{ abc.event_description|linebreaksbr }}</p> 
 {{% for author in abc.event_author.all %}}
              <p>{{ author }}</p>
          {{% endfor %}}


            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

View code:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/home.html', {})





"model class name and function name should not be samm"
def Event(request):
    events=Events.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'polls/events.html', {'events':events})
```

[image]

Models code  is mentioned below:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=300)


    def __str__(self):
        return  self.author_name



class Events(models.Model):
    event_author=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    event_title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=False)
    event_description=models.TextField(blank = True)
    event_image_description = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True,)
    event_release_date = models.DateField(null="false")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_title

    def publish(self):
        self.event_release_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

litle changes are done in template code

Comment: post your model and view

Comment: Share your `Events` model

Comment: And the Polls model.

Comment: added models code above and modified

Comment: `{{%...%}}` thats not right, you need to use `{% ... %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event_author is a manytomanyfield, that means that event_author itself is not something that can be displayed in the template. You need to loop through the manytomany field like so:

```
{% for author in abc.event_author.all %}
    <p>{{author}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

A full example would be:

```
{% for abc in events %}
    <div>

        <h2><a href="">{{ abc.event_title }}</a></h2>
        <p>published: {{ abc.event_release_date }}</p>

        <p>{{ abc.event_description|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        {% for author in abc.event_author.all %}
             <p>{{author}}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: ' author in abc.event_author.all' from 'for author in abc.event_author.all'
getting this error after add above mentioned code

Comment: Whoops, I accidentially typed {{ }} for the for loop which of course should be {% %}. If you copied it with the {{ }} I think that's the problem. Sorry for that.

Comment: i noticed that and changed before still getting an error

Comment: Hmm, not sure what the problem is. Just to make sure, you put the author for loop inside the events for loop right? Like in the expanded example in my answer.